# publish online book with latex

Tags: books, html

I am writing a mathematical book in Latex that I would like to make accessible as an online book, something in the style of [jupyterbook](https://jupyterbook.org/en/stable/start/your-first-book.html), say. **Is there any such service available?** I would be willing to self host such a book on my website if there a service that translates Latex to neatly structured html files.

Comment: [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/) was written in latex for example (using latexml convertor)

Comment: [TeX4ht documentation](https://www.kodymirus.cz/tex4ht-doc/tex4ht-doc.html) is written in LaTeX and compiled automatically by Github Actions.